# Missing some documents after import-spweb for a document library

Tags: document-library, powershell, export, import

I exported a document library with `export-spweb`. After this, I imported it to another site collection with `import-spweb`.

My issue is when I compare the 2 libraries. In the source I have 1272 items and in the destination I have 1243 items.

When I look in the log import I have no errors.

Comment: what is the full export command you executed?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Effectively i had some checked out documents.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

looks like you have 29 documents that are checked out. Make sure that all documents are checked in first. when performing a `export-spweb` it does it on the checked in version. if it doesn't have one then its ignored.